# When should I use the Unicode punctuation space character in French written texts?

Tags: typesetting, character, research, unicode

I couldn't find any authoritative references about this which are [available on public internet](http://www.worldcat.org/title/lexique-des-regles-typographiques-en-usage-a-limprimerie-nationale/oclc/288969704).

the code is `0x2008`.

Comment: What does French have to do with anything?

Comment: What is "the Unicode punctuation character"? [There are lots of them](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Po/list.htm).

Comment: @Jongware : because those kinds of common typesetting rules often change with the language.

Comment: You should use the correct punctuation mark, always, in any language. If that requires the use of Unicode to achieve then do it. I don't know of a single rule in ANY language that says to use an incorrect punctuation mark. Can you show me one?

Comment: @Ryan : sorry I forgot a word inside the question which caused meaning change. The question is about a specific character used in typesetting.

Comment: I believe that's the thin non-breaking space used in "classic" French typography. They have spaces before punctuation marks like `!` but these are thinner than usual and non-breaking to avoid risking having a line start with `!` or similar. There's some info about it here - http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/46/pourquoi-place-t-on-une-espace-avant-les-ponctuations-fortes-why-is-there-a

Comment: @user568458 : No the narrow no-break space is 0x202F, not 0x2008. The punctuation space is the official Unicode description for the 0x2008 character.

Comment: I think you need to step back and read what the SE model is about.  I would love to see more typography questions but, as it sits, I do not think you understand our site and are just randomly asking questions trying to make the argument that "its off-topic here" when it's really you aren't asking questions that can be answered or asking questions that are unclear of the intent so become hard to answer.

Comment: @Darth_Vader : No, I'm sorry if my questions are poorly written/unclear, I didn't wanted to do it. This is more generally linked to my English level. However for asking question which are trivial to answer only for printing professionals : yes.

Comment: The same question was asked there: https://typedrawers.com/discussion/2005/punctuation-space-u-2008 And there are some very useful posts.

Answer (score 3):

It's pretty subjective once you get into different widths of spaces down to such minute details. I don't believe you'll find a specific usage because one does not exist.

> The main difference among other space characters is their width. U+2000..U+2006 are standard quad widths used in typography. U+2007 `FIGURE SPACE` has a fixed width, known as *tabular width*, which is the same as digits used in tables. U+2008 `PUNCTUATION SPACE` is a space defined to be the same width as a period. U+2009 `THIN SPACE` and U+200A `HAIR SPACE` are successively smaller-width spaces used for narrow word gaps and for justification of type. The fixed-width space characters (U+2000..U+200A) are derviced from conventional (hot lead) typography. Algorithmic kerning and justification in computerized typography do not use these characters. However, where they are used (for example, in typesetting mathematical formulae), their width is generally font-specific, and they typically do not expand during justification. The exception is U+2009 `THIN SPACE`, which sometimes gets adjusted.

Source: http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode7.0.0/ch06.pdf

Again it makes no difference if its in French. The only exception are the non-breaking spaces used to distinguish words in languages that don't generally have spaces between words.

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you're asking I would use unicode values when entering data or content into a database and you are offering an API or someone needs to pull data from the API.  Actually rendered characters can cause issues over time or depending on how the code is written can cause catastrophic effects to the rendered output.

Another reason you would use unicode is if your font doesn't actually have the character present and the browser would still be able to render the value correctly based on the unicode.

Answer (score 0):

You should use that character because it’s non-breaking, meaning that your text won’t get separated from the punctuation when there’s too little space.